# CloudFront how to setup reverse proxy on an existing distribution serving website from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront, http-redirect

I have a S3 bucket which hosts a website and is delivered with CloudFront

and right now I have attached the distribution to my apex root domain like - www.xyz.com

So, previously we were using Nginx to serve a static frontend from a webserver root on the same domain - www.xyz.com and had also setup a reverse proxy - www.xyz.com/api/** which routed traffic to upstream backend server on the same machine.

Now, I would like to move the website to S3 but still run the backend API on the same machine and to do so I will have to change my DNS records and point them to the CloudFront distribution.

But, then the existing and previously deployed and running services which use www.xyz.com/api for backend services will break 
So, I want to forward all request on this path pattern to http:///api so that the existing applications don't break.

Is there a way we can achieve this ? i.e -

Forward request from a subpath of CloudFront distribution 
delivering a static frontend from S3 to an external application server ?

---UPDATE---
---Nginx conf to redirect requests---

```
location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4040/api/;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }
```

this is within a server directive which exposes the root domain & frontend to the world currently but now I want to migrate the frontend to S3 and thus only keep this location block /api for compatibility purposes until I update the configuration on all clients.

If so, please suggest how this can be done or what information you need from my side that could help out in getting this done ?

Thanks,

Comment: Include your nginx configuration block related to a reverse proxy.

Comment: added the nginx conf, it just forwards requests from this server to my node app. but what I want is use a cloudfront distribution with this domain and to be able to redirect requests from cloudfrontcname/api to <old_server_ip_with_my_node_app>/api ? am I making sense or going in the right direction ?

Comment: @HarshitLaddha are you able to solve this. I am also having the same problem and needed a solution

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create `api.example.com` in DNS, pointing to your API.

Create a second Origin in CloudFront, pointing to `api.example.com`.  Leave "Origin Path" blank, because it does not do what you might assume.

Create a new Cache Behavior in CloudFront, with the Path Pattern of `/api*`.  Point this to the newly-created origin.

CloudFront will send all requests for `/api*` to `api.example.com` and everything else to the default Cache Behavior Origin, which would be the bucket.

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm after creating the behaviour and a second origin. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I have tried to use your solution but when it gives 307 URL redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure if this would work, but this is the first thing that came to my mind.

1. Register additional domain api.xyz.com and point it to your old machine.
2. Use following nginx `server` configuration block:

   ```
   server {
       server_name api.xyz.com;
       ...
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Redirect all requests from `www.xyz.com/api/...` to `api.xyz.com/...` with the following [Amazon S3 redirection rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects):

   ```
   <RoutingRules>
     <RoutingRule>
       <Condition>
         <KeyPrefixEquals>api/</KeyPrefixEquals>
       </Condition>
       <Redirect>
         <HostName>api.xyz.com</HostName>
         <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith></ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
       </Redirect>
     </RoutingRule>
   </RoutingRules>
   ```

You can also take a look at [AWS Lambda Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html). I am not familiar with it so cannot tell if it can be used for this case.

Comment: Yeah, so I tried this only instead of api subdomain to test things now I added the IP of server instead so it works if I am accessing the website directly through the S3 endpoint but when I try the cloudfront distribution url with this it redirects me to angular app because in CF distribution there is a behaviour set to redirect 404s to index.html of angular app